# Use Wildfly landing page as homepage

Tags: jboss, webserver, wildfly

I'm using Wildfly 10 to provide an app with 2 different servlets. One for the clients and one for the hosts.

So I have following urls:

- Serveraddress/client
- Serveraddress/host

Now I want to use the landing Page of Wildfly with url:

- Serveraddress

as my general homepage for this app and let the users navigate to either client or host.

Is this a way to go or should I set up a usual homepage by one of the masses of webhosters.

My thought was, that I only need one server and one address to serve the web-app and the public homepage.

Are there any performance problems? Or could this be handled without any problems. As far as I understand, the landingpage is just a plain old html homepage, without any session being created.

Comment: Read about deploying a 'root' application!

Comment: Should i serve the normal Homepage also as ear or war file. I don't need any sessions for the HP. Just some information, images and links to both apps.

Comment: If you want to deploy it to a java-ee container yes as far as I know you should. You **could** deploy it to a plain front-end webserver (reverse proxy) if you use that.

Comment: That is my question, can i use the wildfly landing page as plain front-end webserver, or is wildfly not constructed for this situation and it would have a massi e performance impact...

Comment: You could simply replace the `$JBOSS_HOME/welcome-content`.

Comment: That's what i'm currently doing. Does this create any performance problems when using this together with the application server? Should i use an external webserver for this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends the volume of traffic. Fine for most stuff, but using nginx to serve the homepage and then proxy the other calls might be better. You can also later add caching to nginx to reduce the load on your app server or load balance against a cluster of app servers if you need to later

Comment: Do you have any idea about the performance impact of a static page request? For me it seems pretty small, due to the missing session creation... Just return plain html files